# Flash, links inside a non-HTML textfield

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there any way to create links inside large textfields without setting the textfield as an HTML textfield? I don't want to set the link to all the text in the textfield, only to some words in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, at least not easily. you could search for the word, then get the start- and end-coordinates of the letters in question and add a transparent button on top of the textfield.

why don't you want to use a html textfield?

Comment: I currently use it but I thought there was a way to avoid HTML tags (when it comes to create HTML dynamically as you would do with JS or PHP the code can become less readable).

Comment: sorry, but no. you have to save the info which words are links (+ url) somewhere, why not the text itself ... the only thing you could try, is something like [bbcode](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) bit tidier than html